# example codes needed when using OAuthSwift and identityserver3

Tags: ios, swift, identityserver3

I have set up an identity server using identityServer3. Now I am writing an iOS app to authenticate against the identity server. I could not find any example or codes for this setup. The examples I found are all using google, or github etc. My problem is that the call `OAuthSwift.authorizeWithCallbackURL` just switch the screen to safari and then nothing shows up. I suspect that my setup of callbackurl or url scheme is not correct.

Here is my code snippet

**ON server side:**

```
    new Client {
            ClientId = "implicitclient1",
            ClientName = "Example Implicit Client1",
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
            Enabled = true,
            Flow = Flows.Implicit,
            RequireConsent = true,
            AllowRememberConsent = true,
            RedirectUris = 
              new List<string> {"oauth-swift://oauth-callback/TestOAuth2"},

            AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Email
            },
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
        },
```

**on iOS app side:**

```
   let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey: "implicitclient1",
        consumerSecret: "secret",
        authorizeUrl: "https://example.com/idserver/core/connect/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://example.com/idserver/core/connect/token",
        responseType: "token"
    )

    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/TestOAuth2")!,
                                        scope: "openid",state: "",
                                        success: {
                                            credential, response, parameters in
                                            print(credential.oauth_token)},
                                        failure: {
                                            error in
                                            print(error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

When adding URL types to the ios app, I put in "TestOAuth2".

What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. 
Turning on the identityserver3 logging was a tremendous help. I changed the flow from implicit to Authorization Code. ( I am not sure why this was needed but that was how I made it work.) I changed the call back string to "myiosappname://oauth-callback". On the ios app, I put "myiosappname" to plist's URL Types scheme.

I double checked that ssl certificate.

Then it started to work. I hope it helps someone down the road.

HZ